# How to Solve this integration with integration techniques

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How to solve this integration

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^\frac{1}{2}+x^\frac{1}{3}}$$

Comment: Usually, one does either the current answer or $x=u^n$ such that all the exponents in the denominator become whole numbers.  These are the same substitution.

Answer (score 6):

Set $u=x^{\frac{1}{6}}$, then the integral becomes
$$ \int \frac{6u^5}{u^3+u^2}\;du=6\int \frac{u^3}{u+1}\;du$$
which can be handled using long division.